# using a converter while reading xaml from string using XamlReader.Parse()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to load this xaml using XamlReader.Parse() and this code:

```
<helpers:FilterDataGrid 
    xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:URM.Helpers;assembly=URM"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:grid="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:convert="clr-namespace:URM.Converters;assembly=URM"
    ItemsSource ="{Binding PendingContracts}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Margin="20,0,10,0"
    Height ="Auto" 
    Width ="Auto">

    <helpers:FilterDataGrid.Resources> 
         <convert:DateConverter x:Key="DateConverter"/>
    </helpers:FilterDataGrid.Resources>

    <helpers:FilterDataGrid.Columns>
         <grid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Contract Id" Binding="{Binding ContractId}" />
         <grid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Submitted" Binding="{Binding DateSubmitted, {StaticResource DateConverter}}" />
         <grid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Submitted By" Binding="{Binding Submitted_by}" />
         <grid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name" Binding="{Binding Proprietors_Company_Name}" />
         <grid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Term Of Contract" Binding="{Binding TermOfContact}" />
    </helpers:FilterDataGrid.columns>

</helpers:FilterDataGrid>
```

How do I add the converter. I have added the namespace for the converter but I keep getting this error:

'Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:URM.Converters;assembly=URM}DateConverter'.'

I added this is the same manner I added all the other namespaces which work well.

Edit: Parse Code

```
private void Initialize()
        {
            using (var sp = new SilentPartnerDataContext())
            {
                try {
                    PendingContracts = new ObservableCollection<SalesContract>(GetAllContracts());
                    string data = sp.XamlExpressions.Single(c => c.UserControlName == "PendingContracts").XamlText;
                    ContractContent = XamlReader.Parse(data) as FrameworkElement;
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to show data");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are sure that the URM assembly is accessible from the assembly you are loading the xaml?

Comment: its the same assembly and I have the helpers namespace using URM assembly and it works

Comment: And you're 100% certain no namespace mispellings? Could you post the Parse() code?

Comment: added code...very simple - i'm really just testing this out to see if it works...taking out the static resource stuff...the data grid shows up

Comment: Wait `URM` is the assembly this file is in? If so, don't include the assembly in the `xmlns` attribute.

Comment: i've tried it both ways. It doesn't matter whether I leave it out or not.

Comment: Does `DateConverter` have a default constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the DateConverter class is public:

```
public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: so this solved the issue...when I read this over the weekend while at home...I was like no, no, no this not the answer but I no longer get the error...I get a new error stating that `The given key was not present in the dictionary` - Not sure if I should continue the question or create a new one as this is still a part of the question.

Comment: There is only the `DateConverter` key, so that should be easy to solve. Otherwise it's certainly a new question.

Comment: SMH thanks for the 'THAT'S AN OBVIOUS MISTAKE' I fixed it by adding Converter={...}...appreciate the help